# Wordpress arabic category name problem in wp-options of theme

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, arabic

I have wordpress site with arabic category names. in wp-options json of theme in db, the category name are saves such this: "d8a2d985d988d8b2d8b4" but the original category name is "آموزش". how can i fix this problem or convert "d8a2d985d988d8b2d8b4" to "آموزش"?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encoding problem first convert all data in new table with correct collation 
i used utf8_persian_ci work fine in arabic and persian

this function convert :

```
function decode($encode_str)
{
    $temp="";
for ($i=0; $i <strlen($encode_str) ; $i++) 
{ 
if ($i%2==0) {
$temp.="%";
}
$temp.=$encode_str[$i];
}

return urldecode($temp);
}
```

test your data :

```
$str_from_db="d8a2d985d988d8b2d8b4";

echo decode($str_from_db);
```

output:

```
آموزش
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is solved temporarily but the cat name still saved in wrong encoding even with change db and table encoding to "utf8_persian_ci" . is there any way to fix this?

Comment: after change encoding run mysql query to convert all data 
new data add correct